# error message color in symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, recaptcha

i want to change the color of errors that occour when a form is submitted by users, i set

> ```
> .errorMessage{ color:red }
> ```

in main.css, but it dosn't work :(, is there any option for error color in widgets?
i google it but i can't find answer, my symfony version is 1.4.11, and another question is i want to have captcha in my forms, i write this code for that

> ```
>  $this->widgetSchema['captcha'] = new sfWidgetFormReCaptcha(array(
>       'public_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_public_key')
>     ));
> ```

```
    $this->validatorSchema['captcha'] = new sfValidatorReCaptcha(array(
      'private_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_private_key')
    ));
```

but when i echo the form this error occour:

> ```
>  Captcha Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to theme it in template file

```
<?php foreach($form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors() as $name => $error): ?>
<div class="errorMessage <?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You will get something like that:

Captcha Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid